# how to check that the value of variable contains special characters or not in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have stored the value entered in text box in a variable as below

```
var vehicle_no=document.online_booking_b.vehicleno.value;
```

now how to check that the value stored in the variable vehicle_no contains any special characters or not?
here online_booking_b is form name and vehicleno is textbox' id.

Comment: What are these special characters?

Comment: where is the jquery in this code?

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to check for all those special characters, it's easier to use a regular expression:

```
var vehicle_no=document.online_booking_b.vehicleno.value;
if(/^[a-zA-Z0-9- ]*$/.test(vehicle_no) == false) {
    alert('Your string contains illegal characters.');
}
```

The above will only allow strings consisting entirely of characters on the ranges a-z, A-Z, 0-9, plus the hyphen an space characters. A string containing any other character will cause the alert

Comment: this works but now if the user enters correct entry then on submit the form goes to next page but how to get it in the same page and go for next field validation?

Comment: Do the validation for your fields first and then have the form submitted. See http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp if not using jQuery, or http://api.jquery.com/submit/ if using jQuery.

Comment: do one thing like this fist you set a flag in your jquery code on document.ready like this isValidated = false, and errorcount = 0 and as shobit said do your validation first, if it fails make Isvalidated = false and increase your errorCount. Then submit the form the only if the IsVAlidated = true and errorCount = 0

Answer (score 0):

You can use vehicle_no.match() where regex would be something like `/[^a-zA-Z ]+/`. If there's only letters from a-z or A-Z, the match would would return null.

Comment: what about 1,2,3 they will not be catch by `/[^a-zA-Z ]+/`

Comment: So if you want to make sure there are only numbers and letters and spaces, then use `vehicle_no.match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]+/)`.